# How to make a Makefile that includes my header?

Tags: c

I am new to c programming, and I am having a problem with making Makefile for it.

I did like

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -g -Wall -Wvla

OUTPUT = prac

all: $(OUTPUT)

mymalloc.o: mymalloc.c mymalloc.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ mymalloc.c

%: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ mymalloc.o $^
```

and I try to make file with just typing "make"

But it keep says

```
gcc -fsanitize=address -g -Wall -Wvla -o prac mymalloc.o prac.c
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'mymalloc.o'
make: *** [prac] Error 1
```

whenever I try to make it , did I do something wrong?

Thank you.

Edit)

I got it right with using this!

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -fsanitize=address -g -Wall -Wvla
DEPS = mymalloc.h
OBJS = prac.o mymalloc.o



%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

prac: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@  $^
```

Comment: You also need a dependency like: `$(OUTPUT): mymalloc.o prac.o`

Comment: @Barmar Then, do I have to make another prac.o file and add it to make a executable file?

Comment: The problem is that the `%: %.c` rule is triggered for `prac`, but that rule uses `mymalloc.o` without having a dependency for `mymalloc.o`. Maybe read the make manual about "make depend". Or replace the rules with explicit instruction first. Maybe optimize later.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the executable dependent on `mymalloc.o`:

```
%: %.c mymalloc.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ mymalloc.o $^
```

The dependency tells `make` that it needs to execute the rule for creating `mymalloc.o`.

Also your rule for making `mymalloc.o` is wrong. You need `-o` before `$@`:

```
mymalloc.o: mymalloc.c mymalloc.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ mymalloc.c
```

Otherwise it's trying to use the output file as one of the input files.

Comment: I changed it to like that, but I still got a same error..

Comment: Maybe inspect the output of `make -d ...`.

Comment: @RyanLee Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't do as exactly what you say, but I got a big knowledge with the dependency rule on makefile!